# primefaces dataexport from table with column content in ui:repeat

Tags: primefaces, facelets, mojarra

I have a master detail resultset that I present on a datatable.

The detail is fetched and rendered within  to be combined into a single output string that remains in one column.

```
<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">BF Order Contents</f:facet>
  <ui:repeat value="#{order.listOfOrderDetails}" var="orderitem" varStatus="orderitemstatus" >
    <h:outputText value="#{orderitem.product.brand.name}-#{orderitem.product.name}#{orderitemstatus.last ? '':', '}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

On the datatable, that column displays as "Some Brand-Some Product, Other Brand-Other Product"

But when I export to EXCEL, I see:

com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@783622ba

in that column.

Does anyone have any idea about how I can overcome this (within xhtml only). I don't want to alter the backing bean to produce the detail string.

BTW: I'm on PF3.2, Mojarra 2.1.8, EL 2.2.1-b04, JDK1.7, Tomcat7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think its possible , even with overriding  the `exporter class` in the primefaces sources it will be way to complicated...

You probably better `alter the backing bean`

Also, you can add a star on a bit related an issue opened by me [Feature request: Datatables custom filter function - filterFunction (like sortFunction for sort)](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4010&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary)

Answer (score 5):

It can be solved in the below manner.

1. Column having ui:repeat should not be made exportable i.e set exportable="false" attribute for p:column.
2. Add one more column to display the string property (write bussiness logic to convert list of string to a comma seperated string and set it the string property)
3. set the style as display:none; for the new column.
4. so during ui display, the previous column will display and during export the new column will be displayed showing comma seperated list.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a facelet function that does the iteration in Java and returns a string.. this will work just put it to outputText, or do 2 columns one put exportable false and the other make CSS display:none